# NameError: name 'cos' is not defined, sageMath9.4

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, sage, pi

I am writing a Python module using **SageMath9.4**. Basically, I want to import this module into **Jupyterlab** Notebooks (running a SageMath 9.4 kernel) to do calculations etc.

Here is the start of it:

```
class Coxeter_System:
'''This class defines the standard root system associated to an abstract Coxeter group.'''

def __init__(self, coxeter_matrix):
    '''Sets up a Coxeter system and root system. At this stage, limited to up to rank 7. 
    '''
    def set_up_coefficient_space(coxeter_matrix):
        '''Sets up a polynomial ring a Free module over a polynomial ring quotiented by the minimal polynomials of the 
        non-rational cos(pi/m_ij) values. 
        
        This is so roots can be compared using an abstract free module rather than over reals'''
        
        A = coxeter_matrix
        k = len(A.rows())

        # Get the cos(pi/m_ij) which are irrational
        non_rational_angles = [x for x in [cos(pi/x) for x in set(A[i,j] for i in range(0,k) for j in range(0,k))] if x not in QQ]
```

However, when I open another Jupyterlab session, import the Python module and try to create an instance of the object "Coxeter_System", I get the following error (I have tried to do `from math import cos` both from the notebook where I want to import the module to, and in the module itself, but I still get the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!):

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-6b542b6cb042> in <module>
----> 1 W = c.Coxeter_System(Matrix([[Integer(1),Integer(3),Integer(4)],[Integer(3),Integer(1),Integer(3)],[Integer(4),Integer(3),Integer(1)]]))

~/coxeter_groups.py in __init__(self, coxeter_matrix)
     60             return matrix(R,k,B)
     61 
---> 62         R = set_up_coefficient_space(coxeter_matrix)
     63         A = coxeter_matrix
     64         k = len(A.rows())

~/coxeter_groups.py in set_up_coefficient_space(coxeter_matrix)
     17 
     18             # Get the cos(pi/m_ij) which are irrational
---> 19             non_rational_angles = [x for x in [cos(pi/x) for x in set(A[i,j] for i in range(0,k) for j in range(0,k))] if x not in QQ]
     20 
     21             # sort the irrational values of cos(pi/m_ij) in ascending order

~/coxeter_groups.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     17 
     18             # Get the cos(pi/m_ij) which are irrational
---> 19             non_rational_angles = [x for x in [cos(pi/x) for x in set(A[i,j] for i in range(0,k) for j in range(0,k))] if x not in QQ]
     20 
     21             # sort the irrational values of cos(pi/m_ij) in ascending order

NameError: name 'cos' is not defined
```

Comment: `cos` function is not defined in that scope. Have you imported it somewhere in that file?

Comment: No I haven't imported it anywhere. I originally wrote the code for the class in a Juypterlab notebook (running SageMath kernel), and when I call an instance of the class in that same notebook, there is no problem. When I save that code as just a python script and import it into another Juypterlab notebook (running SageMath kernel) - I get that error above.

Comment: The indentation in your class definition looks strange. Therefore, I suggest you do a simple test in a new cell of SageMath, type in `cos(pi/2)` and let it run.

Comment: yeah not sure why it copied over like that, the __init__ function and the one below should be further indented. That part is not the problem. Running ```cos(pi/2)``` in a separate cell works fine.

Comment: Just checked your code. It works without a problem if the indentation is correct and I omit the `c.` and call it like `W = Coxeter_System(...`

Comment: hmm...still didn't work for me. If I call it without the c, it says ```NameError: name 'Coxeter_System' is not defined```. If I run it with the ```c``` then I get an error with the cos.

Comment: Maybe there is some confusion on where you are importing `cos`.  You need to `from math import cos` where you define `Coxeter_System`, not where you import `Coxeter_System`. You will probably need to share more info on how you have done your imports since that seems to be the source of the problem.

Comment: Try saying `math.cos` after importing just to ensure you stay in the right scope.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `math.cos` instead of using cos after `from math import cos`

e.g. `math.cos(pi/x)`

```
import math
math.cos(pi/x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For most IDEs you will have to **import** some of the most popular **math packages**,

```
# Example:

import numpy as np
import math as m
import sagemath as sm
```

**numpy** and **math** you will have no problem using it with a simple `import numpy` in Google Colab or most popular IDEs.

##### What is SageMath?

**SageMath**, previously known as **Sage**, is a computational algebraic system (CAS) that stands out for being built on mathematical and contrasted packages such as **NumPy**, **Sympy**, PARI/GP o Máxima.

##### Install the SageMath package in Jupyter Notebook:

In the case of sagemath, inside jupyter you will have to do some extra steps.

To install the **sagemath** package we must do a pip:

```
!pip install sagemath
```

[image]

The image shows the confirmation within Jupyter

##### Using sagemath

```
# import and add the alias s
import sagemath as s
```

Yo use it we place the **alias** "**s**" in front of the function

```
s.cos(s.pi/x)
```

If **sagemath** does not always work correctly.

**We know the following**: "The philosophy of SageMath is to use existing open-source libraries wherever they exist. Therefore, it uses many libraries from other projects."

For these mathematical functions you can use **numpy**:

```
import numpy as np
np.cos(np.pi/x)
```

It will not fail and also in Jupyter you do not need additional installation.

I hope I've been useful.